# How to update cldrdata.jar up to latest version of CLDR (v31)?

Tags: java, cldr

The CLDR Data, which is distributed with the Oracle JDK is outdated. Is it possible to somehow update it?

Comment: Just make sure it occurs first on the classpath, right?

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a core Java component, it's not likely to be possible without a lot of work. If you really need newer Unicode additions, you should look into a 3rd party library.